# calling javascript from cucumber step

Tags: javascript, selenium, cucumber

Can I call javascript on a page from a cucumber step using the capybara selenium driver? 
specifically i need to generate a change event when a form field is filled (doesnt seem like it does that by default). If so, could you provide an example?

I've tried googling but havent found an answer. thx.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `page.driver.browser.execute_script` or `page.driver.browser.evaluate_script` (the latter will try to return a value)

Here is simple example of such kind of step:

```
When /^I hover and click on "([^\"]*)"$/ do |selector|`
  page.driver.browser.execute_script %Q{
    $("#{selector}").trigger("mouseenter").click();
  }
end
```